# On hour is subtracted when converting a String to NSDate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

This is the code:

```
let dateString = "2015-07-13T17:32:32.781Z"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
var theDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
println(theDate)  // 2015-07-13 16:32:32 +0000
```

One hour is subtracted to the original date during the process. Why?

Comment: Did you set the date formatter's time zone?

Comment: No. Actually I just want it to keep the date as is. Without time zone considerations.

Comment: In order to format a date for output, the time zone will be taken into consideration. If the date formatter does not have a time zone set, I believe it will use the user's current time zone. You can try setting the date formatter's time zone to UTC and see if it outputs the time correctly.

Comment: How can I get the time zone of the original date ? Then I could use it as a reference for the NSDate object.

Comment: `NSDate` objects don't have time zones (they just represent a specific moment in time). `NSDateFormatter`s do, though. I think what's happening is that `dateString` is in UTC (indicated by the fact that it has `Z` on the end), but the date formatter is in a different time zone, so the date _appears_ to move an hour back in time when printed.

Comment: I believe the Z in the time string indicates that the time zone is UTC. I also believe you are losing this information during the conversion by putting the single quotes around the Z character. Remove the quotes and see if it returns correct time. `YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: (Also, I don't think the solution in the question this one supposedly duplicates deals very well with this particular issue. The linked question was more about printing an `NSDate` properly.)

Comment: @MirekE it worked, you can give it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mipadi has explained really well the problem, so I think that you should just set the time zone to UTC.

```
    let dateString = "2015-07-13T17:32:32.781Z"
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    var theDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
    println(theDate)
```